# searching for specific values in pandas data frame and write condition on them

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have student_data data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
student_data = pd.DataFrame({'studen_id':  ['fWz', 'a1m', 'a1m','4Gn','scw', 'scw', 'nF4c', 'a1m', 'scw', '4Gn', 'fWz' ],
'score': [' ', 15, 14, 11, 20, ' ', 9, 19, 17, 3, ' '] })
```

I want to search in this data frame and,
if each student_id has one of 18, 19, or 20 in its scores, it's good and I want to show it by 1 otherwise 0 in a new data frame(final_df), by using pandas or numpy methods and functions.

final_df (at last):

| student_id | ok? |
| --- | --- |
| a1m | 1 |
| 4Gn | 0 |
| scw | 1 |
| nF4c | 0 |
| fWz | 0 |

I write this code:

```
final_df = student_data.loc[(student_data['score'] == 18) | (student_data['score'] == 19) | (student_data['score'] == 20)]
```

but it isn't complete and I want to know which conditions need to complete my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#your sample dataframe:
student_data = pd.DataFrame({'student_id':  ['fWz', 'a1m', 'a1m','4Gn','scw', 'scw', 'nF4c', 'a1m', 'scw', '4Gn', 'fWz' ],
'score': [' ', 15, 14, 11, 20, ' ', 9, 19, 17, 3, ' '] })
```

try:

```
student_data['ok?']=student_data['score'].isin([18,19,20]).astype(int)
```

Finally:

```
final_df=(student_data.sort_values('ok?',ascending=False)
                          .drop_duplicates(subset=['student_id'])
                          .drop('score',1)
                          .reset_index(drop=True))
```

output of `final_df`:

```
    student_id  ok?
0   scw         1
1   a1m         1
2   fWz         0
3   4Gn         0
4   nF4c        0
```

Comment: KeyError: Index(['student_id'], dtype='object')

Comment: @Kia because in your sample dataframe there is a typo in name `student_data =pd.DataFrame({'studen_id':` so correct it to`'student_id':` and then try

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where`

**Ex:**

```
student_data['Ok'] = np.where(student_data['score'].isin([18, 19, 20]), 1, 0)
```